# W10 Client temporary authentication failure when reconnecting network drives

Tags: windows, domain, network-share, windows-authentication, reconnect

The customer has a W10 laptop. The laptop is member of MyDomain. The user has 20 network drives mapped onto his laptop. The server is W2016 Domain Controller.

The user logs in on his laptop using his LOCAL account.
When he arrives at the office in the morning all his network drives are not reconnected.

He gets the error message: "Drives could not be reconnected because the user account is locked"

Indeed in the W2016 security logs there are 5 failed logon attempts. After that the account is locked for 30 minutes.
When, after 30 minutes the user clicks on the mapped network drive (which has a red cross), *the mapped drive reconnects without a problem*.

The credentials of the user for connection the network drive are **local-computer**\username. It is **not** **MyDomain**\username. I have checked this in PowerShell using the gwmi command.

The latter is surprising. I did not even know it was possible to use local credentials to connect to a domain share. But other tests in a test domain verified this. Only the *user name* must be known in the domain.

What I don't understand is why the first attempt to connect the network drives gives an authentication failure. And later the authentication succeeds. I don't know *how much later* as the account remains locked for 30 minutes anyway.

It is not a matter that reconnection should be delayed until the network is UP. It is up, because the server shows authentication failures.

My next approach is to change the credentials for connecting the drive to **MyDomain**\user instead of **local-computer**\user.

That is the most elegant solution. If that doesn not help I will make the connections non-persistent and create a batch file which is executed manually. But that is not as elegant.

I am reluctant to have to user log on onto the domain. First he can be away from the office quite some time, and has to rely on cached authentication. Secondly, his current user profile is 50GB and logging on to the domain creates a different profile. It is a pita to transfer that.

Any ideas as why the first authentication attempts fail? Knowing that they succeed later?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's using the local credentials to connect to the remote, but possibly it sends the credentials to the remote server. Windows will first attempt the username and password that is currently logged on, against the remote server.

So I suppose the username and password is the same on the local machine and on the domain.

As for the locked account, this is probably due to some cached old, no longer valid password. You can clear this on the laptop with `net use * /d`. Note that it will remove all the connections...

You can confirm where the lock out come from by checking the Security event logs on the domain controller. The [LockedOutStatus](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15201) tool is particularly helpful here to find on which domain controller the lock out happened and at exactly what time (I know I have 50+ security events per second in my logs so it is kind of needed to know the exact second of the lock out).

Comment: Note that the reconnection fails only during the instant the laptop gets back on the network. Later attempts are successful. And yes, I found where the lock came from. The message is "invalid user name or password". But I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: gwim shows the credentials used to connect to a mapped network drive. These are in the form local-computer\username. So it IS using the local credentials to connect to the remote. Apparently the attempt to use those credentials is successful. The security logs show that the failed attempts also used this user name from this machine.